# Restricting Users Using Middlewares - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two roles in my app `admin` and `users`. Both roles are using a middleware called `auth`. Now in the application, when i login as a admin, i am not able to route to **user page** (that is perfect).

But when i login as user, i am able to route to **admin page** but my auth must prevent the user from accessing the admin page. Currently, that is my issue... What am i not doing right?

Below is my code

**AuthMiddleWare**

```
 if (Auth::check())
        {

        if(Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')->first() == "admin")
        {
            // return $next($request);
            return Redirect::to('/admin/dashboard');

        }

        else if(Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')->first() == "user")
        {
            return Redirect::to('/user/dashboard/');
        }

        else{
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']), function () {

    Route::get('dashboard','Controller@show');

}

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'User', 'middleware' => ['auth']), function () {

    Route::get('dashboard','Controller@show');

}
```

Comment: What if you just dump `Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')->first()` right after `Auth::check` and see for yourself whats wrong with it. Also you can use [contains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-contains) on the collection: `Auth::user()->roles->contains('name', 'admin')`, which returns boolean.

Comment: @Kyslik, The users roles are returned when i dump

Comment: How many roles? If they have both admin / user roles then obviously order matters and when you do `->first()`, well you get the first role; which is probably always `admin`.

Comment: @Kyslik, No.. It is able to specify the role of the user who is currently logged in

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `== 'users'` or you have a typo in the question.

Comment: What package do you use for roles / permissions management? Also as I noted in my first comment do not use `->first()` use contains instead. This way if user has both roles the `admin` one has priority.

Comment: Don't do it in one middleware. Add one more middleware in admin's route where you would check if user is not an admin and in that case make redirection to `'user/dashboard'`. In auth middleware just check for session in other words if visitor is logged in. In admin's route you make additional check to be sure one that is accessing is actually an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    if(in_aaray('admin', Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')->all()))
    {
        // return $next($request);
        return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
    else if(in_array('user', Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')->all()))
    {
        return redirect('/user/dashboard/');
    }
    else{
        return redirect('login');
    }
}else{
    return redirect('login');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to make custom auth in laravel and make different table for admin and user